Is it possible to have a two way binding on component render
Parent component:
@page "/parent-component
<ChildComponent @bind-Name="@name" />
<h1>@name</h1>
@code {
  private string name = "Hugo";
}

Child component:
<button @onclick="UpdateName">Update</button>
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }

  private async Task UpdateName()
  {
    Name = $"Hi {Name}";
    await NameChanged.InvokeAsync(Name);
  }
}

When going to the url /parent-component, the H1 says Hugo. And when I click on the button, the text updates to "Hi Hugo" - just as expected.
However, is it possible to remove the button, and have the child do it logic, in this case just to add "Hi", when the component is rendered?
I have tried using OnInitializedAsync, and OnParametersSetAsync but that don't update the value on the parent component.

" just to add "Hi","   Where?  At the moment you're just updating the Parameter which is a NONO.

You should almost certainly use a service. Questions before I answer:  What RenderMode are you using and where is Interactivity set [Global or Per Page/Component]?

The just "Hi" is a simple version of the component that I wish to create.
I use InteractiveServer with prerender set to false.

See the answer below on how to use a state service.  To populate/persist it add a "no content" component to MainLayout that checks local storage for a value and persists it when the state changed event occurs.

Parent Component
@page "/"
@page "/Home"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<Counter @bind-Name="@name" />
<h1>@name</h1>
@code {
    private string name = "Hugo";
}

Child Component
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await NameChanged.InvokeAsync($"Hi {Name} From Child");
    }
}

You can use OnInitializedAsync but if u use OnParametersSetAsync without proper checks it results in an infinite loop. This happens because every time you modify the parameter and invoke the NameChanged callback it triggers a re-render of the parent component, which in turn re-invokes OnParametersSetAsync in the child component

Your code is modifying a Parameter.  It may work here, but it's considered bad practice [  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ].  Just do await NameChanged.InvokeAsync($"Hi {Name} From Child");.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis, in the real project, I have a state with information that's used on most pages. The component is meant to make sure the state is set; if it's not, it will set it from localStorage. If localStorage isn't set, it will redirect to a page to set the data.
It's not needed on all pages, but on most, which is why I thought I would use a component and include it on every page where this logic is required. If it's bad practice to do this in a component, can you recommend a way to achieve this? Thanks

@Orgaard - see comment on your original question

You can use In-memory state container service to realize it.
1.create a service.cs:
public class LayoutService
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public event Action? OnChange;
 
    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
 
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
 

2.config in program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<LayoutService>();

3.parentcomponent:
@page "/parent-component"
@inject LayoutService LayoutService
<ChildComponent @bind-Name="name" @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<h1>@LayoutService.Name </h1>
@code {
    private string name = "Hugo";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        LayoutService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}

4.ChildComponent
@inject LayoutService LayoutService
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.SetName($"Hi {Name}");
    } 
}

The result is :


@MrCakaShaunCurtis, in the real project, I have a state with
information that's used on most pages. The component is meant to make
sure the state is set; if it's not, it will set it from localStorage.
If localStorage isn't set, it will redirect to a page to set the data.
It's not needed on all pages, but on most, which is why I thought I
would use a component and include it on every page where this logic is
required. If it's bad practice to do this in a component, can you
recommend a way to achieve this? Thanks

I write an example for you and hope this can help you.
1.Install the package ASP.NET Core Data Protection
2.Import the package in the _import.razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtectedLocalStore

3.Create a state provider parent component that encapsulates the state provider logic.
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@if (isLoaded)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
        @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
}
else
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}

@code {
    private bool isLoaded;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public string CurrentDate { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var result = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<string>("Date");
        isLoaded = true;
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            Navigation.NavigateTo("set-date");
        }
        else {
            CurrentDate = result.Value;
        }

    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedLocalStore.SetAsync("Date", CurrentDate);
    }
}

4.Routes.razor
@using AreaTest.Components
<CounterStateProvider>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
     </Router>
</CounterStateProvider>

5.DateTest.razor
@page "/Date-test"

<h1>Date</h1>

<p>Current Date: <strong>@CounterStateProvider?.CurrentDate</strong></p>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private CounterStateProvider? CounterStateProvider { get; set; } 
}

6.SetDate.razor:
    @inject NavigationManager Navigation
@page "/set-date"
<h3>setDate</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SetCurrentDate">set Date</button>
@code {
    private async Task SetCurrentDate()
    {
        await ProtectedLocalStore.SetAsync("Date", DateTime.Now);
        Navigation.NavigateTo("date-test", forceLoad: true);
    }
}

The result are :



Hi Hugo.  If you look at the OP's comment on the answer below he want's to use local storage to persist the date.  Would you like to add that to your answer rather than me producing another answer?

I update my answer and realize the local storage function
